# grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist

Tags: grub

This is just documentation for a problem I ran into. I was creating a hybrid multiboot USB stick on 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 using [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multiboot_USB_drive) Arch tutorial and the `--target=i386-pc` command gave me the following error:

```
grub-install: error: /usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/modinfo.sh doesn't exist
```

See answer for solution....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked up this file in the Ubuntu package archives and found it was part of the `grub-pc-bin` package. I tried to install that package, but it had bad dependencies.

However, since I knew I only needed those i386 modules, I just downloaded and unpacked the package, then moved the files into place manually like so:

```
cd /tmp
sudo apt-get download grub-pc-bin
dpkg-deb -R grub-pc-bin_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.16_amd64.deb grub/
sudo mv grub/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc/ /usr/lib/grub/
```

Now you should be able to try again and it should work.

(Note: Your `apt-get download` command may yield a file with a different version than the one shown. If you get errors on the `dpkg-deb` line, make sure you're targeting the file you just downloaded.)

Comment: For some unknown reason, my target was set as `x86_64-efi` platform was giving error for not finding efi directory. Then I changed target which gives this error. Now I used your answer to find the actual package